# Struggling to use callbacks in JavaScript with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-callback

I am having some trouble implementing a callback into my JavaScript that uses AJAX. First off, the script reads from a file and places into a variable:

```
jQuery.get('userdata/' + username + '.txt', function(data) {
    var userid = data;
});
```

Then that variable is being used in the following function, which reads from a .json file and picks the result that **only** contains the value in `userid`.

```
function loadContacts(filter) {
    var contacts = (function () {
        var contacts = null;
        $.ajax({
            'url': 'userdata/' + username + '.json',
            'dataType': "json",
            'success':  function (data) {
                contacts = data;
                contacts = contacts.filter(function(i) {
                    return i.id == userid;
                });
            }
        });
        return contacts;
    })(); 
    // some code for (filter) here
}
```

The problem here is that before jQuery has had time to create `userid` and read from the file specified, the `loadContacts` function is already trying to read from `userid` so it comes back with an unidentified variable error.

I have spent the last 2/3 hours trying to learn how to implement a callback in AJAX, but I have had no luck after trying quite a few different variations.

I understand that by implementing a callback, essentially I am delaying the `loadContacts` function to wait for a success message back from `jQuery.get`, so it doesn't try looking for `userid` before it has been created, I just can't seem to get it to work.

Could anyone help me?

I have already tried learning from that [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call?lq=1) post but I don't get it?

Answer (score 2):

As the AJAX request is asynchronous you are returning a value from your `loadContacts()` function before any data is received. You need to pass a callback function to the function which can be executed after the AJAX request completes. Something like this:

```
function loadContacts(filter, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'userdata/' + username + '.json',
        dataType: "json",
        success:  function (data) {
            var contacts = data.filter(function(i) {
                return i.id == userid;
            });
            callback && callback(contacts);
        }
    });
}

function doSomethingWithContacts(contacts) {
   console.log(contacts);
}

loadContacts('foo', doSomethingWithContacts);
```

Answer (score 0):

easiest way would be to call the loadContacts function from within the result of the first get request.

```
var filter = function(){...};
var contacts = false;
jQuery.get('userdata/' + username + '.txt', function(data) {
    var userid = data;
    contacts = loadContacts(filter);
});
```

You could also make use of the deferred functions of jQuery

Answer (score 0):

How about a little excursion into promises
to fetch data asynchronously, synchronize these calls and process the data.

```
//creating a few "promises"
var pUserId = $.get('userdata/' + username + '.txt');
var pData = $.ajax({
    'url': 'userdata/' + username + '.json',
    'dataType': "json"
});

//filter pData by pUserId, as soon as both are available
var pUserdata = $.when(pUserId, pData).then(function(userId, data){
    return data.filter(function(item){
        return item.id === userId
    })
});

//just log these three, as soon as they are available
$.when(pUserId, pData, pUserdata).done(function(userId, data, userdata){
    console.log("userId:", userId);
    console.log("data:", data);
    console.log("userdata:", userdata);
});
```

And it's up to you, how you want to wrap that into specific functions.

And don't mix a filter with a function that executes an ajax-call. Because then you have to make an ajax-call every time you want a subset of this data. Separate the refreshing of the data and the filtering.